# linux less command search invisible character

Tags: linux, search, character, invisible, less-unix

I want search one invisible character(control character, such as 0x05) using less command in Linux. 
I find the character is displayed as **^E** in less. I can not search it by directly using the characters **"^E"** . Neither <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>ctrl+e</kbd> in VI or just search by `/\0x05`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> means something special at the beginning of the search field regardless of how it is entered. Type another non-"special" character first, then press the sequence, then remove the first character.

Comment: I couldn't make sense of this answer.  What is the correct way to 'press the sequence' for these control characters?

Comment: @conradlee: Hold down Ctrl, press and release the other key, and then release Ctrl. Repeat until done.